# MySQL field 'option' is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

MySQL query is

```
 SELECT option as value, name as text from jos_components where parent  = 0 and enabled=1 order by name
```

I have a table `jos_components` which have field name `option`. I want to run above query but it gives me an error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option as value, name as text from jos_components where parent   = 0 and enabled=1' at line 1
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`option` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). You'll have to surround it with backticks in your query. Try this:

```
SELECT `option` as value, name as text from jos_components where parent  = 0 and enabled=1 order by name
```